# Passing parameters as arguments in OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I have just started to learn OOP. I am still trying to understand how everything works. I am trying to make a new function that will basically allow me to create a new object by passing the parameters of said class.

Is this even possible, and if so what am I doing wrong?

As stated, still learning so any advice will be appreciated.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.persName = name;
  }
  myName() {
    return "My name is " + this.persName;
  }
}

function getPers(_perName, fullName) {
  _personName = new Person(fullName);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getPers(John, "John Doe");
});
```

Comment: What is `John`? Also I presume that you want to `return _personName` from the function. I know you're just using this as a learning exercise, but it's quite redundant to have a function simply for creating an object instance; that's the job of the constructor.

Comment: I totally agree with Rory, also you don't need to use JQuery with that. You can get the same result with JS only.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following exapmle. Please note there is not much logic init. The example is just to show you how OOP can work. Of cause, there are many other and better ways to got with that, but for the first try, it should be good to use.

```js
class Person {
    //declare the constructor with required name values and optional age value
    constructor(firstName, lastName, age = 0) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    //declare a typically setter, e.g. for age
    setAge(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    //declare a getter for the person with age
    getPerson() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + ' is ' + this.age + ' years old.';
    }
}

//here you got with some function within you need to define a new person
function getCreatedPerson(firstName, lastName, age = 0) {
    //define the person with required firstname and lastname
    const person = new Person(firstName, lastName);
    //use the setter to set age of person
    person.setAge(age);
    //return the person by using the person getter
    return person.getPerson();
}

//here you can call the createdPerson function
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(getCreatedPerson('John', 'Doe', 32));
});
```

Hope it helps a bit to understand how it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take the `fullname` as a parameter to your function and pass it through to the OOP method or constructor you're calling.

But you can't take a "reference to a variable" as an argument, like you tried with `_perName`/`_personName`. Instead, use the `return` keyword to return the created object:

```
function createPerson(fullName) {
  return new Person(fullName);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var john = createPerson("John Doe");
  … // use john
});
```